# Reading outlook Sent email when multiple accounts are configured

Tags: c#, outlook

I'm trying to read my Sent emails from outlook using C# and i have 3 mailboxes configured in my email. 
Is it possible that i can specify in the code to read the emails form any of the account

Say, i can use a parameter where i can specify from which account mails should be retrieved?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Namespace.Stores` collection to access the particular store and call `Store.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)`.

Comment: Couldn't succeed as it is returning an error saying store does not have a getDefaultFolder method. Can you please elaborate more on the solution

Comment: Store.GetDefaultFolder method was added in Outlook 2013. What version of Outlook are you using?